# AngularJS detect which input has been changed

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Data is retrieved in my AngularJS app via `$http.get` and rendered like this:

```
# Angular
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.cart = {};

    $scope.cart.retrieve = function() {
        // make $http to retrieve data
        .success(function(results) {
            $scope.cart.contents = results
        });
    };

    $scope.cart.update = function(itemId) {
        // make $http request to update cart
    }
});

# HTML
<table ng-init="cart.retrieve()">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in cart.contents">
                <td>{{ item.price }}</td>
                // item quantity input field
                <td><input type="number" name="quantity" on-change="cart.update(item.id)"
                ng-model="item.qty"></td>
                <td>{{ item.price * item.qty }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

When the item quantity is changed in input field, the function that passes *item id* fires: `$scope.cart.update = function(itemId) { ... }` . How do I retrieve this new quanity value for this particular item that triggered on-change event. Is there something in angular like `this` I can use inside the function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass item to your `cart.update` function:

```
on-change="cart.update(item)"
```

And then use the `qty` of this `item`

```
$scope.cart.update = function(item) {
    // do whatever you want with
    // item.qty
}
```